# How can I spawn in an item I don't have for testing purposes?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have a new Steam account. Because I'm new, I currently do not have anything found for the soldier.

I want to spawn in a Market Gardener to test with it, but I don't know how. I also don't want to go on itemtest.

I also have `sv_cheats 1` enabled

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered just buying or trading for one?

A Strange* Market Gardener hovers around $0.60 on the [Steam Community Market](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Strange%20Market%20Gardener).

Otherwise, you can trade item for item on sites like [backpack.tf](https://backpack.tf/classifieds?item=Market%20Gardener) - most listings for the Market Gardener ask for two weapons/1 scrap metal in return (sometimes listed as '0.11 ref').

<sub>* 'Strange' weapons track kills but are otherwise identical to regular weapons</sub>

Comment: I don't have money

Comment: @HalpMe - You can still earn weapons in-game and trade them though, right?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 main ways you could go about doing this.

#### Borrow an item from the Mann Co Store

1. From the TF2 main menu, click on "Shop"
2. Go to the "Items" section
3. Search for/find the item you want
4. Click on the item, then click "Try it out"

You will then have the item for free for 1 week. It can be used in all servers, however you can only do this with one item at a time.

#### <del>Use the itemtest menu</del>

1. <del>Open any map</del>
2. <del>In the console, type `itemtest`</del>
3. <del>Once the itemtest menu opens, check the box of the class you want to test weapons for (in this case, Soldier)
   There should now be a box, among others, labelled "Weapon."</del>
4. <del>Click "Add" next to the weapon box</del>
5. <del>Select the item you want from the dropdown menu, then press "OK"</del>
6. <del>Click "Apply Test Items"</del>

<del>One thing to note with itemtest is that it will not work properly with bots.

This will only work on the map you're currently on.</del>